# How to Import a model with textures applied?

Tags: texturing, import

I have downloaded [a model](http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/ferrari-california-93936.html) from this [website](http://tf3dm.com/).

It comes with all the textures as `.tga` files.

I want to import all the files into blender so it looks exactly as it does on the website, textures applied and everything.
I've searched around for how to do this with no results.

Can someone help or guide me through doing this?

Comment: I thought the textures were added automatically.. What formats did you try?

Comment: I go to Blender File > Import > modelname.obj  Try downloading it see if it works for you maybe.

Comment: The textures are imported for me, the only difference I can see is that some material settings are different (color, mirror, transparency, etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need to enable the *3DS Import/Export Addon* in the *User Preferences* (Menu: File / User Preferences)

[image]

Then Import the .3ds file (Menu: File / Import 3D Studio (.3ds)
some of the UVMaps don't match the textures you would need to [reassign them](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Unwrapping).

Enable *Transparency* in the *Material Settings* for glas parts:
[image]

[image]

You would also need a few lamps in your scene, in *Object Mode* <kbd>A</kbd>Lamp/Hemi and place them e.g. in front of the model, then you will also see the textures.

Comment: Hey, after Importing the .3ds model this is what is shown: http://novsstudio.com/pic.png   Is that the wasy it should be shown? If so, how do I get it to look like the picture, I don't believe any of my textures are being applied.

Comment: @novs12 You won't see any textures in solid view, try rendering or switching to textured view.

Comment: @novs12 You need to adjust some values, but editing the UV-mappings wouldn't be as trivial as you seem to expect, I added a rendered image.

Comment: I had some issues importing because the model was packaged in a separate directory to the textures. Not sure if 3ds even supports paths in filenames. Either way the texture filename character limit is pathetic. Moving to the same dir fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

Using Blender 2.73a just go to 
File > Import > Wavefront (.obj)
Browse from the extracted downloaded folder for file .obj extension (in my case it is DBR9.obj of size 2.8Mb.)
The whole beautiful complete frame of the car model should open right away in your editor.
I just played for Blender for an hour and it is fun to learn up.