# How to import and export blender files with textures

Tags: export, import, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I've created my first plant from scratch in Blender 2.77a with Cycles Render.
This is what I did next to colour the plant:

1. UV unwrapped each plant body individually and hand texture painted.
2. UV unwrapped one leaf and hand painted in texture paint.
3. I have duplicated the original leaf and modified it.
4. I have repeated step 3 for each single leaf.
   This is the final result:

[image]

I have tried to export the file with 3D Studio, Collada and OBJ but every time I had the same result: a grey object.
I tried to reassign all the UV maps manually but it seems that when I joined the different parts in one mesh, all the UV maps showed unwrapped pieces overlapping each other...

[image]

I'm just learning so I won't panic at this stage but is there a way to export and import complicated objects without loosing all the data related to their textures? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It depends, see if helps - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/importing-obj-with-mtl-and-image-not-working-properly, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/how-to-import-a-model-with-textures-applied, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47915/when-i-save-something-as-an-obj-file-the-texture-does-not-save-with-it-why

Comment: Thanks! That was very nice but when I export to obj files it takes ages for my laptop to process the data. It was much faster for me to export to either collada or 3ds studio. Anyway, problem solved, I did what I didn't want to do to save time, I reassigned everything manually. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: If you create that plant in Blender and continue using in Blender you could use [link or append](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html) to bring all the data in the scene.

Comment: Thanks Zak! I have also tried to pack the data into a .blend file after having packed my UV images but I've got the same result. I guess I'll have to play around with it a bit longer. I love Blender, I've only been using it for a few months, I'll definitely try to use link or append as you suggested. Thanks for the hint and good luck with whatever you are doing!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM SOLVED!

This is how I did it:

1. Make sure the object to be exported (plant) is selected in object mode
2. File: Export: 3ds
3. I opened the scene (room.blend)
4. Select A twice to make sure everything is deselected
5. File: Import: 3ds
6. The object (plant) is grey
7. With the object selected switch to edit mode
8. Deselect everything again by pressing A
9. Hover your mouse over the parts you have created individually and press L
10. The selected part will be highlighted (ex. leaf)
11. Go to Material (On the right side of the screen)
12. A list of the original materials is there but they are all blank
13. Select the corresponding material (ex: leaf)
14. Go to Use Nodes/Color and select the dark grey area on the right indicated by a circle
15. A menu will appear: select Image Texture
16. Open the file with the UV map you created (ex:UV_MAP_leaf)
17. For colors without the UV map, I had to recreate them (ex: pot, dish)

Repeat these steps with every single part in the object and that's it!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this touble when exporting as obj files to iClone5.  Solid colours would export ok but textured surfaces wouldn't be textured.
I had to manually readjust the UV settings in iClone to match those exported from Blender.  I did this by trial and error.  Scrolled the settings in iClone's UV panel until I'd see a flash of the correct texture, then  pursue a finer setting from there.  All would be fine after that, but it was a pain.

Hope this solves your problem.

Nice work BTW.

Comment: Yeah, I had to do the same though I exported my file from blender to 3ds and then imported it back to my room scene in Blender. I had to manually reassign all the UV maps and re-create the colours of the plant pot and dish. I I just wish there was a faster way though. Anyway, everything looks great now. Thank you very much for your explanation!

Comment: My pleasure @Angel.  I'd only used Blender for model creation over the last 18 moths but when the  PC went out in a shower of sparks, I switched to a slow backup and was forced to use Blender, discovering it was able to do almost everything I'd previously paid a small fortune for!!     If you use the OpenGL renderer, you don't age too much when rendering!  Ok for Video FX. Probably a bit basic for the 'artist' among us.